# How to update JArray values with C# and Json.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm getting an array of items from Web API (lines before this are omitted):

```
var cars = JArray.Parse(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result)
```

Inside the cars JArray it looks like this:

```
"cars": [{
            "id": 1,
            "make": "Audi",
            "color": "red"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "make": "Mercedes",
            "color": "red"
        }, {
            "id": 3,
            "make": "Ford",
            "color": "yellow"
        }]
```

I would like to update the color of Ford to red if Audi is also red.

How can I do that with C# and Json.NET?

Comment: You can use json path along with json token

Comment: eeek dont do `.Result` on an async. Recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON you provided is not valid for me to parse, so ive made an assumption to demonstrate. which wraps your sample in a root JSON object.

You can query the JOBject using `keys`. i.e to access `cars` propery in the JSON you can use `o["cars"]`. With this approach you can see i use a bit of Linq to figure out if Audi is red, and if so, you can perform direct modifications to the `o` object and set values accordingly.

This is the most basic approach, without any further code.

```
void Main()
{
    var json = @"
    {
        ""cars"": [
            { ""id"": 1, ""make"": ""Audi"", ""color"": ""red"" }, 
            { ""id"": 2, ""make"": ""Mercedes"", ""color"": ""red"" }, 
            { ""id"": 3, ""make"": ""Ford"", ""color"": ""yellow"" }
        ]
    }";

    var jObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json);
    var jArray = jObject["cars"] as JArray;

    Console.WriteLine("Before: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jObject));

    var audiIsRed = jArray.Any(car => car.Value<string>("make").Equals("Audi") && car.Value<string>("color").Equals("red"));

    if (audiIsRed)
    {
        jArray.First(c => c.Value<string>("make").Equals("Ford"))["color"] = "red";
    }

    Console.WriteLine("After: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jObject));
}
```

An alternative could be making a POCO to deserialize the results, which would contain, for example a `List<Car>` and then you could do all modifications with C# and no JSON.NET then serialize that result back to JSON.